# I cant figure out how to add my "et" object to the group , i keep getting this error "'Group' object has no attribute 'et_set'

Tags: python, django

Views.py

```
def etudiant_inscription(request):
    form = form_etudiant()
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = form_etudiant(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            et = form.save()
            et.save()   
            group = Group.objects.get(name="etudiant") 
            group[0].et_set.add(et)
            return HttpResponseRedirect('/etudiant_login')
        else:
            return HttpResponseRedirect('/accueil')
        
    return render(request,'etudiant_inscription.html',{'form':form})
```

Models.py

```
class etudiant(models.Model):

    identifiant = models.CharField(primary_key=True,max_length=20)
    nom = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    prenom = models.CharField(max_length=20) 
    date_naissance = models.DateField(blank=True,null=True)
    photo = models.ImageField(upload_to=None, height_field=None, 
    width_field=None, max_length=100,blank=True,null=True)
    adresse = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    email = models.EmailField(max_length=50,null=True,blank=True)
    état = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    situation = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    password = models.CharField(max_length=20)
```

Error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Mega-PC\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py", line 47, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "C:\Users\Mega-PC\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 181, in _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Mega-PC\OneDrive\Desktop\testtttt\app\views.py", line 50, in etudiant_inscription
    group[0].et_set.add(et)

Exception Type: AttributeError at /etudiant_inscription/
Exception Value: 'Group' object has no attribute 'et_set'
```

what am I doing wrong exactly?

Comment: Share your models...

Comment: What is `group[0]` doing here?

Comment: Where is you're Group model ?

Comment: @AchrafBentabib i didnt understand your question sorry im quite new to django

Comment: You want to call et_set method of Group Object right ?    Where is the models.models of your Group object ?  Share it ( class Group(models.Model ))

Comment: i imported the Group class from django.contrib.auth.models , is that wrong?

Comment: Can you explain what do you want to achieve ? What's the point of your etudiant class, and why are you using a Django Group ? The Django group does'nt have et_set method.

Comment: i want to make groups so i can manage permissions and my users easier

Comment: So why are you using the method et_set ? This method does not exist...

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.